# the number of input values varies

Tags: matlab, initialization, k-means

Actually what I am doing is that I want to write my own function of k-means clustering. But, for giving the initial inputs, I don't know how to do that in Matlab. What I mean is, one input of the function is the number of cluster centers, k, and then we need to input the k initial values the function will use in the first iteration. But the k may change and the number of initial values will change. So how can I do this using Matlab. I want the input to be an integer k, and k initial values. With different k, different number of initial inputs changes, so what I can do?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: use `input` command to make user enter the value of `k` and the `k` initial values can be chosen randomly. So you can just choose `k` random data points as: `yourData(randi(size(data,1),[k 1]),:)`. This is assuming you store 1 data sample per row and your features go across columns.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, I don't want to use random initial values but I want to define certain initial values. What should I do?

Comment: Then make user enter those too using `input` in a for loop. Are you sure you want to do this, even when data is 10 samples, 10 features and 3 clusters, the user has to enter 3 vectors, each of length 10, that's too much.

Comment: How to use `input` as users will manually give the input data? Can you give an example?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, How to use `input` as users will manually give the input data? Can you give an example? How to relate this function with the real input from a keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

why do you need k+1 inputs? Can't you just use one input?
For example with clustering in 2 dimensions:

```
function [ returnValues] = kMeans( centers)
% get number of cluster centers
k = size(centers,1);
for i = 1:k
    % select each center individually:
    center = centers(i,:);
    % process
end
```

An example call with three cluster centers [1,2] , [3,4] and [5,6] would then be:

```
values = kMeans([1,2;3,4;5,6]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With variable nuber of inputs:

```
function retVal = kMeans(varargin)
% at least k has to be given
if length(varargin) < 1
   error('Wrong number of arguments given'); 
end
k = varargin{1};
disp(['K: ',num2str(k)]);
%check if k+1 inputs are given
if length(varargin) ~= k+1
   error('Wrong number of arguments given'); 
end
% process inputs
for i = 1+(1:k)
    center = varargin{i};
    disp(['Input Center ',num2str(i-1),' : ', num2str(center)]);
end
end
```

When called with `kMeans(2,[1,2],[3,4])` it outputs:

```
K: 2
Input Center 1 : 1  2
Input Center 2 : 3  4
```